# SHA1 кодировка и декодировка

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-security

Использую Spring MVC+Security и для отображения bootstrap

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("ru.skanerxxl.rambler")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(serviceSecurity)
.passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
}
}
```

Здесь пароль юзера декодится.

Как подключить SHA1 чтобы при регистрации закодировать пароль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо получить пользователя перед сохранением, зашифровать ему пароль, например таким методом:

```
public void encodeUserPassword(User user){
    String hashString = user.getPassword();
    ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    String hashOutput = encoder.encodePassword(hashString,null);
    user.setPassword(hashOutput);
}
```

и сохранить в БД.